# Python dbus and while loop

Tags: python, dbus

I need to have both a dbus event loop based on signals and a `while True:` main loop in Python. What are some possible and recommended ways to accomplish this?

Greatly simplified, but basically combining something like this:

```
dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
bus = dbus.SystemBus()

bus.add_signal_receiver(properties_changed,
        dbus_interface = "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties",
        signal_name = "PropertiesChanged",
        arg0 = "org.bluez.Device1",
        path_keyword = "path")

mainloop = GObject.MainLoop()
mainloop.run()
```

and this:

```
# Main loop.
while True:
  read_adc()
```

From what I can tell, mainloop.run() starts a blocking process..

Comment: Are you sure you need a "while True" loop? You can still make regular calls to a function from the GLib mainloop (See at GLib.timeout_add() and GLib.idle_add() ). If you really need two loops then you need to deal with threads and all the problems they bring.

Comment: read_adc() would read input from a remote control, for a good "feel", you'd want to give that high (maybe even highest) priority. I'd rather have the dbus signal come in a bit later if both are busy at the same time.